# http://127.0.0.1 returning 401 Unauthorized

Tags: centos, plex, firewalld

I have a CentOS 7 box and have a service running on port 32400 (Plex Media Server) which is trying to pull some information via HTTP to `http://127.0.0.1:32400/library/changestamp` but a 401 response is being returned. I have added the `lo` interface to the active zone in firewalld, but still getting 401.

The server's IP is 192.168.1.77 and `http://192.168.1.77:32400/library/changestamp` returns 200 (I have added the appropriate rules to `firewalld`).

So, how can I make `http://127.0.0.1:32400/library/changestamp` return 200? If I turn `firewalld` off then it does, but obviously I need `firewalld` enabled.

Answer (score 0):

OK, it turns out that enabling masquerading on the zone is preventing traffic to `127.0.0.1`

So, what I have done is set up 2 zones - `external` and `internal`. I assigned the `lo` interface to the `internal` zone and the NIC (`eno1`) to the `external` zone.

I then left masquerading enabled on the `external` zone, but disabled it for the `internal` zone, allowing traffic to the `lo` interface (`127.0.0.1`) through.

Not sure if this is the correct/best way to do it, so I welcome any comments!

Hope this helps others.